# Issue with plotting decimal list with F#'s R Type Provider

Tags: r, f#, data-conversion, type-providers

I'm parsing a CSV with F#'s CsvProvider and successfully creating two lists :

`let times = [ for row in airinfo.Rows -> row.Time ]`

`let passengers = [ for row in airinfo.Rows -> row.AirPassengers ]`

`times` is a decimal list and `passengers` is an int list.

Ultimately I'm trying to run:
`R.plot (times, passengers)`

For starters though `R.plot passengers` works, but `R.plot times` doesn't, which leads me to believe that the problem is in plotting a decimal list.

I get the following exception:

> System.Exception: No converter registered for type
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1[[System.Decimal, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] or
>   any of its base types
>
> at RProvider.RInteropInternal+convertToR@164.Invoke (System.String
>   message) [0x00001] in <57161c90b86b2a10a7450383901c1657>:0     at
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Core.PrintfImpl+StringPrintfEnv`1[TResult].Finalize
>   () [0x00012] in <5893d081904cf4daa745038381d09358>:0     at
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Core.PrintfImpl+Final1@224[TState,TResidue,TResult,A].Invoke
>   (Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2[T,TResult] env, A a) [0x00038] in
>   <5893d081904cf4daa745038381d09358>:0     at
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Core.OptimizedClosures+Invoke@3253[T2,TResult,T1].Invoke
>   (T2 u) [0x00001] in <5893d081904cf4daa745038381d09358>:0     at
>   RProvider.RInteropInternal.convertToR[inType] (RDotNet.REngine engine,
>   inType value) [0x00061] in <57161c90b86b2a10a7450383901c1657>:0     at
>   RProvider.RInteropInternal.REngine.SetValue (RDotNet.REngine this,
>   System.Object value, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1[T]
>   symbolName) [0x00001] in <57161c90b86b2a10a7450383901c1657>:0     at
>   RProvider.RInteropInternal.toR (System.Object value) [0x00019] in
>   <57161c90b86b2a10a7450383901c1657>:0     at
>   RProvider.RInterop.passArg@447 (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T]
>   tempSymbols, System.Object arg) [0x00123] in
>   <57161c90b86b2a10a7450383901c1657>:0     at
>   RProvider.RInterop+argList@468-1.GenerateNext
>   (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String]& next)
>   [0x000d8] in <57161c90b86b2a10a7450383901c1657>:0     at
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilerServices.GeneratedSequenceBase`1[T].MoveNextImpl
>   () [0x00017] in <5893d081904cf4daa745038381d09358>:0     at
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilerServices.GeneratedSequenceBase`1[T].System-Collections-IEnumerator-MoveNext
>   () [0x00001] in <5893d081904cf4daa745038381d09358>:0     at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T]..ctor
>   (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] collection) [0x00077] in
>   <48b95f3df5804531818f80e28ec60191>:0     at
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.SeqModule.ToArray[T]
>   (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] source) [0x0006a] in
>   <5893d081904cf4daa745038381d09358>:0     at
>   RProvider.RInterop.callFunc (System.String packageName, System.String
>   funcName, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] argsByName,
>   System.Object[] varArgs) [0x0001d] in
>   <57161c90b86b2a10a7450383901c1657>:0     at
>   .$FSI_0012.main@ () [0x0002f] in
>   <511174b5879343f6b1c4aa72a97ef951>:0     at (wrapper
>   managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke
>   (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)    at
>   System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj,
>   System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder
>   binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo
>   culture) [0x00032] in <48b95f3df5804531818f80e28ec60191>:0

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: re-format the exception text as block quote

Comment: The R provider is fairly low level, and it doesn't know about some F# (like option) and .NET types. Just convert your decimal into float or some other number format that can be digested by it. You also need to probably box it. Can you add the full code you are calling? This as an example cannot be reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to convert the decimal list into a number type the RProvider knows about. Here's an example that works for me:

```
#load @"..\packages\RProvider\RProvider.fsx"

open System
open RDotNet
open RProvider
open RProvider.graphics

let floatList = [1. ..10.]
let decList = [1M .. 10M ]

R.plot(floatList) // this works
R.plot(decList) // Syystem.exception
```

> System.Exception: No converter registered for type
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1[[System.Decimal, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Cul ture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
>   or any of its base types

But you can convert your list into another type:

```
decList 
|> List.map float 
|> R.plot
```

[image]

Also, if you want to use one list as a label maybe you should convert into string, not float as I did above.